# The Heisenberg uncertainty principle in the time-frequency plane

Tags: fourier-analysis, wavelets

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle says that it is impossible to have a signal with finite support on the time axis which is at the same time band limited.

Is the following reasoning correct: When I look to the time-frequency plane of the depicted wavelet basis, it looks like the basis functions are band limited due to their compact support on the frequency axis and have a compact but **infinite** support on the time axis as well. So they are localized in time and frequency. But as a consequence of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, they could never be perfectly localized in time and frequency at the same time.

[image]